# Get COM port (Serial Port) of newly connected USB device in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, wmi

I am working on a C# application. I have to trigger an event whenever a new USB drive is connected to the PC. This is my code for now:

```
public class usbState
{
    public usbState()
    {

    }

    private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
        }
    }

    private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
        }
    }

    public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");

        ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
        insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
        insertWatcher.Start();

        WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");
        ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
        removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
        removeWatcher.Start();

        // Do something while waiting for events
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000000);
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        usbState usb = new usbState();


        BackgroundWorker bgwDriveDetector = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwDriveDetector.DoWork += usb.backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        bgwDriveDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgwDriveDetector.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgwDriveDetector.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

This code works fine and gives the properties of the attached USB, but issue is that it does not give the PORT on which USB is connected. How can i get the port number on which we have attached the USB.

Answer (score 0):

i use this method to return the exact name of the port (COM1, COM2...) , you should provide the expected name of the device for example (arduino, Camra...) and a search time out in ms :

```
private string GetCOMName(string sExpectedPortName, int iTimeOut)
    {
        Stopwatch sp = new Stopwatch(); sp.Start();
        string sPortName = "Unknown";
        bool isPortFound = false;
        while (sp.ElapsedMilliseconds < iTimeOut)
        {
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
            {
                var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

                var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();

                foreach (var port in portList)
                {
                  // Pass here the expected name of your port , for example (Arduino or Camera...)
                    if (port.Contains(sExpectedPortName))
                    {

                        var start = port.IndexOf("(") + 1;//add one to not include quote
                        var end = port.LastIndexOf(")") - start;
                        sPortName = port.Substring(start, end);

                        isPortFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            // if the port is found then we go out from the whileloop
            if (true == isPortFound)
                break;
        }
        // return the result
        return sPortName;
    }
```

Comment: ManObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPDeviceID = " + PNPDeviceId); . . . I am using this, but its saying invalid query. Any help ? @Erwin Draconis

Comment: I can't use your approach because i will have multiple devices attached and i think your approach will not work on that

Comment: invalid means that the port is not available or you do not have sufficient right to access the resource, did you try with SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'") ?

Comment: Yes, your query works, but i want to query by using "PNPDeviceID" @Erwin Draconis